# CSS3 filter: drop-shadow spread property alternatives

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to use a CSS3 (webkit) drop-shadow filter to place a white glow around any given transparent png with approximately the same dimensions, and `-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 22px rgba(255,255,255,0.8));` is working great for solid images. The problem is  that it mangles images that are primarily text somewhat horribly. All the shadows blend together instead of creating a proper tight glow effect.

[image]

I need to be able to use spread instead of blur so that the shadows don't just become a big blob behind some of the text, but apparently while the standard says that [you should be able to specify a spread property, you still can't](http://thenewcode.com/598/boxshadow-property-vs-dropshadow-filter-a-complete-comparison).

I've heard that SVG drop shadow filter can be used to achieve the same effect as drop-shadow (and in fact must be used in Firefox) but I haven't been able to find a way to apply a spread property to that either.

What kind of workarounds exist for this problem, if any?

Comment: I would suggest **not** using images for text. Use **actual** text and then `text-shadow`. This would also be good for SEO purposes.

Comment: I'm being supplied rather complicated logos to apply these drop shadows to, usually composites of several different fonts, sometimes with other images overlaid. As much better as it would work, recreating them in HTML is not an option. Just baking the shadows into the pngs (although it was my first response) is also not an option.

Comment: I wrote a codepen tool to help people do advanced shadow manipulation using SVG filters - enjoy http://codepen.io/mullany/details/sJopz/

Comment: It's actually not part of the standard yet, https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#funcdef-drop-shadow `Note that spread values or multiple shadows are not accepted for this level of the specification.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I figured out how to replace the non-functioning spread property using SVG filters. Big thanks to Michael Mullany though his answer wasn't 100% what I need. Here's the filter I'm using:

```
<filter id="drop-shadow">
    <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="6" in="SourceAlpha" result="dilated"/>

    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" in="dilated" result="blurred"/>

    <feFlood flood-color="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" in="blurred" result="flooded"/>

    <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </feMerge>
</filter>
```

feMorphology dilate operator replicates the functionality I wanted very nicely, making it easier to give the text a 'glow' effect that conforms a lot more strictly to the outline of the text.

[image]

(Oddly, feFlood does nothing and I'm unable to get a white glow, but that's a problem for another question. The filter also eats up 100% of a single core as long as it's open in a tab in the latest Chrome. Oh well.)

Answer (score 12):

Another way to achieve the the feeling of spread is use multiple drop-shadow filters.

```
filter:  
  drop-shadow(1px 1px 2px white)
  drop-shadow(-1px -1px 2px white)
  drop-shadow(1px -1px 2px white)
  drop-shadow(-1px 1px 2px white)
  drop-shadow(1px 0px 2px white) 
  drop-shadow(-1px 0px 2px white)  
  drop-shadow(0px 1px 2px white) 
  drop-shadow(0px -1px 2px white);
```

This results in a hard white border with a normal softer dropshadow behind it. Stacking more of the same color can give the desired results as the original question.

[image: White border using multiple dropshadows]

Comment: This doesn't necessarily work well for text, but it's a great substitute for the spread attribute. Note that each filter must be separated with a space, not a comma, unlike the box-shadow property.  I use multiple identical drop-shadows to create a heavier shadow, but you can also offset each one up, down, left, or right by the same amount: `5px 0`, `-5px 0`, `0 5px`, and `0 -5px` for a truer spread.

Comment: i ended up using this approach, but ran into performance issues due to the excessive use of filters. I was able to resolve those issues using this answer from another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29577985/4325849

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use an SVG filter to customize your shadow spread:

```
  <filter id="f1" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="160%" height="160%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" result="blurOut" stdDeviation="8"/>
    <feOffset in="blurOut" result="dropBlur" dx="0" dy="0"/>

  <feComponentTransfer in="dropBlur" result="dropBlur2">
    <feFuncA id="alphaFunc" type="gamma" amplitude="2" exponent="1.5" offset="0"/>
  </feComponentTransfer>

    <feComposite operator="over" 
     in="SourceGraphic" in2="dropBlur2"/>
</filter>
```

Interactive demo here: http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/sJopz

Comment: this would be really helpful for something I'm trying to do, but your link 404s :(

Comment: link working now

Answer (score 0):

Drop shadow on text (with your 22px) will never look good, as the text and letter spacing are much closer. If using text, you should use `text-shadow` (or maybye `text-stroke` is also an alternative for you, see my demo):

http://jsfiddle.net/fHzX7/

Comment: See comment above. I'd love to, but the image I supplied was just using simple text as a placeholder. The actual "mostly text images" are complicated logos that I can't easily recreate.

Comment: What about using less distance (for example `drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px white)` instead of `drop-shadow(0px 0px 22px white)` ? Otherwise this is impossible. There is `backface-visibility:hidden` but this only works (correctly) in Firefox so far (for drop-shadow)

Comment: I see. I suppose it doesn't look _awful_ currently but I was definitely hoping I could find some way to force a spread-like property. Thanks for the help anyway.