# CSS3 filter performance & CPU usage: Why do certain filters tax the CPU?

Tags: jquery, performance, css, cpu-usage

Consider this demo from [David Nuon](https://zunostudios.com/blog/development/170-css-effects-convenience-at-a-price):

http://zunostudios.com/demos/css32014-demos/filters.html

As David notices in his post:

> You'll notice that the more the sliders are to the right, the less
>   responsive the page becomes.

And that is true. After I altered the image, I saw how my CPU began to work a lot.

What I could not answer to myself is WHY after all the css modifications the page is so unresponsive. Like all the animations are 2fps.

If the job is done why it keeps working?

**Edit:**
With the help of xengravity I could see that maybe after all the filters are to the right it seems that the GPU does the following at an insane rate:

1.- takes the original image.
2.- modifies it (math calculations, blabla, etc).

But always starting from the original image. Maybe thats why it seems all so slow....

**Edit: Added demo into a snippet for future posterity**

```js
   var update_filter = function () {
 
    
    var styles  = [

    'grayscale( ' +  parseInt($('#grayscale').val()) * .01 + ')', 
    'blur( ' +  $('#blur').val() + 'px)', 
    'sepia( ' +  $('#sepia').val() + '%)', 
    'brightness( ' +  parseInt($('#brightness').val()) * .01 + ')', 
    'contrast( ' +  $('#contrast').val() * .1 + ')', 
    'hue-rotate( ' +  $('#hue-rotate').val() * 3.6 + 'deg)', 
    'invert( ' +  $('#invert').val() + '%)', 
    'saturate( ' +  parseInt($('#saturate').val()) * .1 + ')', 
    'opacity( ' +  parseInt($('#opacity').val()) * .01 + ')', 


    'drop-shadow( ' +  (function (n) { 

      return '0px ' + 
             '0px ' + 
             n + 'px ' + 
             'black)'; } 
      )($('#drop-shadow').val()) , 
   ];

    var styles = '-webkit-filter:\n' + styles.map(function (e) { return '\t' + e;} ).join('\n') + ';';
   
    $('#image').attr('style', styles);
    $('#code').val(styles);
   };

   $('#reset').click( function () {

    $('#grayscale').val(  $('#grayscale').data('default') );
    $('#blur').val(  $('#blur').data('default') );
    $('#sepia').val(  $('#sepia').data('default') );
    $('#brightness').val(  $('#brightness').data('default') );
    $('#contrast').val(  $('#contrast').data('default') );
    $('#hue-rotate').val(  $('#hue-rotate').data('default') );
    $('#invert').val(  $('#invert').data('default') );
    $('#saturate').val(  $('#saturate').data('default') );
    $('#opacity').val(  $('#opacity').data('default') );
    $('#drop-shadow').val(  $('#drop-shadow').data('default') );

    update_filter();


   });

   $( 'input[type="range"]').change(update_filter );

   update_filter();
```

```css
body, html {
  background: #fff;
 }
 
 .wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;

  background: #fff;

  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 60px auto 0 auto;

 }

 .controls {
  background: #ddd;
  
  width: 250px;

  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
 }

 .image {
  background: url(transparency.png);
  
  width: 550px;

  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0; 
 }

 .controls {
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
 }

 .controls li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
 }

 .controls li span {
  font-size: 13px;

 } 
 .controls li span::after {
  content: '()';
 }

 .controls li input {
  color: #333;

 
  float: right;
 }

 #code {
  position: absolute;

  left:0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -155px;

  border:0;

  font-family: monospace;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image">
   <img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/WdIGZ1t.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
   

 <ul class="controls"><li>
 <span>blur</span> 
  <input type="range" id="blur" min="0" max="100" value="0" data-default="0">
 </li>
 
 <li>
 <span>grayscale</span> 
  <input type="range" id="grayscale" min="0" max="100" value="0" data-default="0">
 </li>
 
 <li>
 <span>drop-shadow</span> 
  <input type="range" id="drop-shadow" min="0" max="100" value="0" data-default="0">
 </li>
 
 <li>
 <span>sepia</span> 
  <input type="range" id="sepia" min="0" max="100" value="0" data-default="0">
 </li>
 
 <li>
 <span>brightness</span> 
  <input type="range" id="brightness" min="0" max="100" value="100" data-default="100">
 </li>
 
 <li>
 <span>contrast</span> 
  <input type="range" id="contrast" min="0" max="100" value="10" data-default="10">
 </li>
 
 <li>
 <span>hue-rotate</span> 
  <input type="range" id="hue-rotate" min="0" max="100" value="0" data-default="0">
 </li>
 
 <li>
 <span>invert</span> 
  <input type="range" id="invert" min="0" max="100" value="0" data-default="0">
 </li>
 
 <li>
 <span>saturate</span> 
  <input type="range" id="saturate" min="0" max="100" value="10" data-default="10">
 </li>
 
 <li>
 <span>opacity</span> 
  <input type="range" id="opacity" min="0" max="100" value="100" data-default="100">
 </li>

 <li><button id="reset">Reset</button></li>
 

  </div>
  <textarea id="code" cols="20" rows="11"></textarea>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'll notice that the only time the performance is hit hard is when you either use blur or drop-shadow.  If you play with any of the other filters there is very little cpu usage or any indication of a performance hit.

**The first thing to understand is that not all filters are created equal.**

Most filters modify pixels on a 1:1 level which is a relatively straight forward calculation.

However when you introduce anything with a "blur" or "shadow" it may no longer be a 1:1 calculation.

Say you use the radius parameter and set it to 5px.  You now need to look at 5x the amount of pixels to calculate what the blur should look like.

When you compound this with other filters on top of this the calculation required increases.

Modern browsers are able to utilize the GPU to help with these calculations to make the process faster but you'll notice devices with weak GPU's suffering.

So to answer your question specifically.  The CPU isn't running after the filter is applied, it's actually still in the process of calculating! When you put in crazy values like the example allows you to (e.g. a radius of 100px) you can imagine how intensive that calculation will be on the CPU.

Here is a quick guideline on performance for CSS filters:

- grayscale / fast
- sepia / fast
- saturate / fast
- hue-rotate / fast
- invert / fast
- opacity / variable
- brightness / fast
- contrast / fast
- blur / slow
- drop-shadow / slow
- url() / variable

Comment: "The CPU isn't running after the filter is applied, it's actually still in the process of calculating!" - But Why? How? I see the image changed, the filters are applied and Im shouting to my computer: "Hey CPU, the work is done, why you are still working?!". I mean, the work is done right? all the math calculation it had to do, has been done. The CPU should not work. anymore.

Comment: It's not done that's my point.  You can test this by using Chrome.  Open up Chrome DevTools and go to the Timeline tab.  Enable the paint checkbox.  After the image is done being rendered press the record button.  Record 5-10s and then review the timeline.  You can see how the CPU is being utilized.  After the filter has been rendered and if the screen remains static there is no CPU usage.  However, if you adjust the width of the browser window the screen needs to be repaint the image and filter so it will utilize the CPU again to do so.

Comment: On a second check, you are right. I saw that the CPU is not working after all the filters are to the right, BUT its the GPU that is working, thats why it seems all so sluggish (moving the filter again its like a 2fps animation). So, it seems that the GPU does the following at an insane rate:  1. takes the original image. 2. modifies it (math calculations, blabla, etc). But always starting from the original image. Maybe thats why it seems all so slow....

Answer (score 34):

The main problem with this "app" is painting. And if you apply some filter effects, or even go crazy with the slider, you are actually killing CPU with computationally expensive operations which are perfectly intended for GPU. It is very good at this stuff. If you use timeline tool and trace your app you will see massive green bars which indicates painting and painting is happening on the main thread(CPU). What you need to do is to manually promote elements that use these filter effects to a **layer**. You can do that with some hacks like `transform: translateZ(0);` or new `will-change: transform;` and after that you will see massive improvement in responsiveness of your app. But on mobile devices generation 2012 and below you can forget good performance, this is just too much for them.

Try to add this code through the dev tools and observe the result, if it is not faster let me know ?

```
 img#image {
  transform: translateZ(0); /*for older browsers*/
  will-change: transform;
}
```

Comment: Good, but sadly underrated answer!

Comment: True! I just did a performance test, and this dropped the "Painting" time from 690ms to 63ms, without an increase in any of the other sections. (in Chrome 58, 64-bit)

Comment: Though note that you have to be careful where you place the "will-change: transform" attribute. When I place it on the div which has its "scrollLeft" and "scrollTop" props changed, the fps goes from ~30fps to 60fps. When I place it on the div which is inside that scroll-view, it *reduces* the performance to ~10fps. Make sure you know where to place it, and that you verify the performance before and after. (I use this helpful Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fps/efnoodpnfiocmgkbeolmnaofoooiblpm?hl=en)

Comment: It seems like I needed to add `will-change: transform` to a parent parent, not the one that had `filter` applied (an image). The `blur()` was causing painting to continuously run at 60 fps despite no animations or scrolling, and after applying it to the parent, it dropped down to just a few and scrolling became smooth again.

Comment: You my man are a legend! My site went from painfully slow to not even noticing a difference just like that.

Comment: Your answer saved me so much time. Thanks