# Animation in parallel with backdrop-filter kill the CPU

Tags: css, css-animations, cpu, blur, keyframe

my problem is next:

I have couple of infinite keyframes css animations with only "transform" property inside on my page, like this:

```
@keyframes movement-rotation-effect-first {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  17% {
    transform: translate(-6px, -6px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-6px, -6px);
  }
  34% {
    transform: translate(6px, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(6px, 0);
  }
  51% {
    transform: translate(0, 6px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 6px);
  }
  68% {
    transform: translate(6px, -6px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(6px, -6px);
  }
  85% {
    transform: translate(-6px, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-6px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

animation: movement-rotation-effect-first 10s linear infinite;
-webkit-animation: movement-rotation-effect-first 10s linear infinite;
```

Also I have couple of non-animated elements with backdrop-filter blur:

```
@supports (-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(25px)) or (backdrop-filter: blur(25px)) {
   backdrop-filter: blur(25px);
   -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(25px);
}
```

When I comment out all animations in CSS and left only backdrop-filter in CSS - everything OK.

When I comment out backdrop-filter in CSS and left only animations - everything OK.

When I left both - my CPU become crazy, fan become loud.

backdrop-filter blurred elements and animated elements are different elements, so backdrop-filter not inside animations.

I already tried:

```
.animation-fix {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  will-change: transform;
}
```

Can anybody help with workaround to save CPU and my Mac fan?
Because I need both animations and backdrop-filter on page

Thanks for any help

**UPDATE:**

I uploaded it to server, so You can test
https://frontend.psdev.lv/test-tmp/

Comment: How many do you have ? i only see a huge spike *50%* after adding 100+ elements, one element the cpu wiggles between 7% to 10% seems fine to me, you'd expect that from an infinite animation. but then again you never know.

Comment: @Zohini I have 50deg C + 1500rpm normally.
And same If i run animation or backdrop-filter.
But as soon as I run both - in 5s I have 85deg C + 4000-5000rpm + fan loud too much.
Then if I comment it out, then it go back to normal.

Comment: I uploaded to server and added link in description, so You can check. Blur element is ".main-info-wrapper"

Comment: Can animated "slow scaling" image under blur background impact on it?
Please check https://frontend.psdev.lv/test-tmp/

Comment: At this hero block I have 5 animations and 2 blur effects with backdrop-filter. And it kill my CPU and Fan after 30-40 sec of just staying on this page..

Comment: Probably has to do with the fact that there's animation behind the blur, and therefore the blur will have to be constantly recalculated, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550422/css3-filter-performance-cpu-usage-why-do-certain-filters-tax-the-cpu

Comment: @Zohini Yes I also thought about it. Just tested again, and same CPU damage without animation under blur area.
But :)
I also commented out animation that was over blur area. And it works :)
So - any animation over/under blur area - kill CPU, without it - everything perfect! :)