# Why is 'filter' not a known CSS3 property name in Windows 8 apps?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2012, svg, windows-8

I'm recreating my own [**pen**](http://codepen.io/NomNom99/pen/ByXLrq?editors=010) for a Windows 8 desktop app.
As you can see, it works perfectly on Codepen.
Except for the CSS, I've modified the `-webkit-` to `-ms-`.
But this line in CSS sheet

```
filter:url("#mercury");
```

gives an error in Visual Studio 2012 :

> validation (CSS 3.0): filter is not known property name

What is the cause of this? What is the alternative to `filter` attribute while creating Windows 8 Desktop application?

Comment: The `filter` CSS property that is based on SVG filters is not implemented in Windows 8. It will only be introduced in Windows 10 with IE11 and Project Spartan.

Comment: Not even on desktop apps?

Comment: No, desktop apps use most if not all of the same implementation as MSHTML (which is what IE uses).

Answer (score 0):

> What is the alternative to filter attribute while creating Windows 8 Desktop application?

Use an SVG `filter` element instead:

```
  <filter id="f1" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="160%" height="160%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" result="blurOut" stdDeviation="8"/>
    <feOffset in="blurOut" result="dropBlur" dx="0" dy="0"/>

  <feComponentTransfer in="dropBlur" result="dropBlur2">
    <feFuncA id="alphaFunc" type="gamma" amplitude="2" exponent="1.5" offset="0"/>
  </feComponentTransfer>

  <feComposite operator="over" in="SourceGraphic" in2="dropBlur2"/>
</filter>
```

then reference the element using the ID in your hash URL.

**References**

- [SVG Filter Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/fdkmI)
- [SVG Filter Effects in IE10](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/10/14/svg-filter-effects-in-ie10.aspx)
- [CSS3 filter: drop-shadow spread property alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486039/1113772)